# What is the bundling tool used by React native

Tags: react-native

Does React Native use any tools like webpack or rollup etc. to do the bundling? How can we tweak into the bundling process?

Any pointers to know the bundling process is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This stackoverflow answer might help you out, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36773789/708807

Comment: React Native has it's own packager. Didn't find much documentation about it beside of how to [bundle static resources](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.48/docs/images.html#static-image-resources). There is also third party replacement called [Haul](https://github.com/callstack-io/haul) that uses webpack. Maybe looking how it's build would be helpful?